# Directed system of irreducible modules

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups, automorphic-forms, hecke-algebras

I have a question on a paper in the Corvallis proceedings on automorphic forms.  **Background**: Let $G$ be a topological group of td type.  This means that $G$ is Hausdorff, and every neighborhood of the identity of $G$ contains a compact open subgroup.  The Hecke algebra $H(G)$ is the vector space of all locally constant functions of compact support $G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with multiplication given by convolution:

$$f_1 \ast f_2(g) = \int\limits_G f_1(x)f_2(x^{-1}g)dx$$

$H(G)$ is in general not commutative or unital, but for each open compact subgroup $K$ of $G$, $H(G,K)$, the subalgebra of $H(G)$ consisting of all bi $K$-invariant functions, has an identity element $e_K = \frac{1}{\mu(K)} \chi_K$.

A representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ is called *smooth* if the stabilizer of each vector is an open subgroup of $G$.  Every smooth representation is associated to a canonical nondegenerate $H(G)$-module structure given by a vector valued integral

$$\pi(f)v = \int\limits_G f(g)\pi(g)v \space dg$$

$V$ is irreducible if and only if it is simple as an $H(G)$-module, and a $G$-map is the same thing as an $H(G)$-linear map.  Moreover, $V$ is irreducible if and only if $V^K = \{ v \in V : \pi(k).v = v \textrm{ for all } k \in K \}$ is simple as an $H(G,K)$-module for a fundamental system of open compact subgroups $K$.

A smooth representation is called *admissible* if $V^K$ is finite dimensional for all open compact $K$.

**The problem**: let $G_1, G_2$ be groups of td-type, and let $G = G_1 \times G_2$.  The Hecke algebra of $G$ can be identified with $H(G_1) \otimes H(G_2)$.  I'm trying to understand why every irreducible admissible representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ decomposes as a tensor product of irreducible admissible representations $V_1 \otimes V_2$ for $G_1$ and $G_2$.  My reference is the article *Decomposition of Representations into Tensor Products* by D. Flath:

[image]

The reference [2] is a result in Bourbaki, *Algebra*, Chap VIII, which says that if $A, B$ are unital algebras over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $P$ is a simple unitary $A \otimes_k B$-module, then $P$ is isomorphic to $M \otimes_k N$ for simple modules $M, N$ over $A, B$.

What I'm confused on is where the maps $b_1, b_2$ are coming from, why they can be chosen to be injections, and why they can be chosen to form a directed system over the fundamental system of open compact neighborhoods $K_1 \times K_2$ of $G_1 \times G_2$.  I would appreciate any reference or a hint.

Comment: You should find simple and motivating examples.